# Kotlin: Unresolved reference

Tags: kotlin

> Kotlin: Unresolved reference: totalFee

I'm just doing this little dummy program to practice yet it's saying that `totalFee` is unresolved when trying to print the value to the screen. I've looked it over for some time now and can't figure out why. 
`daysRented` is an int that is declared previously in the program.

```
if (daysRented <= 10){
    if(insPolicy == true){
       val totalFee = (shortTermRate * daysRented) + (insRate * daysRented)
    }
    else{
        val totalFee = shortTermRate * daysRented
    }
}
else{
    if(insPolicy == true){
        val totalFee = (longTermRate * daysRented) + (insRate * daysRented)
    }
    else{
        val totalFee = longTermRate * daysRented
    }
}
println("Rental fee: $totalFee")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` is an expression, so I would write this as

```
val totalFee = if (daysRented <= 10){
    if(insPolicy == true){ // can just be if (insPolicy)
        (shortTermRate * daysRented) + (insRate * daysRented)
    }
    else{
        shortTermRate * daysRented
    }
}
else{
    if(insPolicy == true){
        (longTermRate * daysRented) + (insRate * daysRented)
    }
    else{
        longTermRate * daysRented
    }
}
```

which really should be improved to

```
val termRate = if (daysRented <= 10) shortTermRate else longTermRate 
val totalFee = 
    if (insPolicy) {
        (termRate * daysRented) + (insRate * daysRented)
    } 
    else {
        termRate * daysRented
    }
```

or even

```
val totalFee = termRate * daysRented + 
    (if (insPolicy) insRate * daysRented else 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I appreciate you showing me how to shorten it too. Thanks for help

Comment: You may want to accept the answer then: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
val totalFee: Int
if (daysRented <= 10){
    if(insPolicy){
       totalFee = (shortTermRate * daysRented) + (insRate * daysRented)
    }
    else{
        totalFee = shortTermRate * daysRented
    }
}
else{
    if(insPolicy){
        totalFee = (longTermRate * daysRented) + (insRate * daysRented)
    }
    else{
        totalFee = longTermRate * daysRented
    }
}
println("Rental fee: $totalFee")
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this style for such a case. Only if there is more than one variable, or assignments aren't last actions.