# Kotlin: Unresolved reference while simulating NPE

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I am trying some practice programs.
When I am trying to simulate NPE using !! operator but my program throws below error:

> Kotlin: Unresolved reference: length

I took the program reference from [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/kotlin/null-safety-in-kotlin/#throwNPE)

And my program is:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    var b: String? = "Hello"     // variable is declared as nullable
    var blen = b!!.length
    println("b is : $b")
    println("b length is : $blen")

    b = null
    println("b is : $b")
    blen = b!!.length // <-- Here is the error
    println("b length is : $blen")
}
```

I am expecting `NullPointerException` in this code.
Any idea what is wrong here?

P.S.: I have already seen similar questions - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360819/kotlin-unresolved-reference) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58317946/kotlin-unresolved-reference-removeat) but nothing relevant I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is smart enough in this case to see that `b` is always `null` in this exact place. So it can in theory smart cast `b` to the type `Nothing?` (a type holding only the null value).

Not sure if it actually does, but if it did, then it would be natural to get this error because `b!!` would be of type `Nothing` which doesn't define a `length` property.

I guess it's better to detect that at compile time than having an NPE at runtime.

EDIT: if you extract `b!!` into a variable, you will actually get an "unreachable code" error, and you can see `x` here is of type `Nothing`:
[image]

Comment: So does it mean that we can't get NPE in Kotlin as compiler by itself evaluating values of variables?

Comment: You can, but not in such a simple case where it's obvious to the compiler. You can make an NPE by using a property instead of a local variable, because in that case the compiler cannot prove that it's really null (another thread could be setting the value to something non-null in parallel)

Comment: Got it.
I managed to get the NPE by adding this code `var x: Int
    x=1
    if (x==1)
        b = null`